# Python 3 Menu with Quit option

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, menu

I'm trying to create a sort of CLI menu in Python (very new to this) and having an issue with the quit option mostly, it won't actually quit and jumps to the "Oooops that isn't right" option instead, or repeats the last step. It does seem to work if you put it as the first choice though

I know I must be doing something daft. I've tried just putting the variable at the end of the function, as well as the menu function itself but that didn't seem to work.

Snippet below if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
def my_menu():
choice = input("Please choose an choice: ")
choice = choice.lower()

while (choice != "quit"):
    if choice == "b":
        a_thing()
        my_menu()
    if choice == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Oooops that isn't right")
        my_menu()

def a_thing():
    print("a thing")

my_menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to input the choice another time at the end of the loop, remove the call to the my_menu() function and remove the if choice=="quit" block (because the loop will automatically quit when the choice is set to "quit")

```
def my_menu():
    choice = input("Please choose an choice: ").lower()

    while (choice != "quit"):
        if choice == "b":
            a_thing()
        else:
            print("Oooops that isn't right")
        choice = input("Please choose an choice: ").lower()

def a_thing():
    print("a thing")

my_menu()
```

Or you can remove the loop and just verify using if statements and in the case of "quit" you just put return to break the loop

```
def my_menu():
    choice = input("Please choose an choice: ").lower()

    if choice == "b":
        a_thing()
    elif choice == "quit":
        return
    else:
        print("Oooops that isn't right")
    my_menu()

def a_thing():
    print("a thing")

my_menu()
```

Comment: Option 1 looks to have done the trick! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and on its first iteration it runs as expected. After that, the recursive call to `my_menu()` starts to cause problems.

Walking through it, first you enter some random string, "hi", and it will enter the while loop and use the `else` case. This will call `my_menu()`, which then calls *another* while loop. When you enter that new while loop, any exiting that you do (e.g. `break`) won't exit the first loop, only the loop that your currently in, so you're in an infinite loop because you can never "go back" and change the value of `choice` in the first loop.

A way you could achieve this behavior with the least amount of changes to your code would be like this:

```
def my_menu():
    choice = ""
    while (choice != "quit"):
        choice = input("Please choose an choice: ")
        choice = choice.lower()
        if choice == "b":
            a_thing()
        if choice == "quit":
            break
        else:
            print("Oooops that isn't right")

def a_thing():
    print("a thing")

my_menu()
```

(I removed your recursive calls to `my_menu()`, moved the input lines to within the loop, and initialized `choice` before the loop)

Comment: This is looking like a great answer! The only snag I'm having now, is it's printing the Ooops message at the end of doing the thing. I tried making it a parameter and setting it before calling the function but that doesn't seem to have done the trick. Med's answer looks to have done the trick though

def my_menu(choice):

choice = ""
my_menu(choice)